# Archivos estáticos Django + Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en django que se encuentra en producción en heroku. Los archivos estáticos los estoy sirviendo con apache desde otro servidor.

Pero al usar la aplicación, obtengo un error en la consola como este:

```
Font from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Por lo que estoy teniendo errores como que los popups en el admin no funcionan.

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'https://example.com/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'https://example.com/static/'
```

Comment: Tip: Busca en Google "Django CORS"

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo @toledano, tienes que tener django cors en tu configuracion. Siga estos paso para hacerlo.
 1. `pip install django-cors-headers`
 2. Cambia `settings.py` asi:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: Ya había realizado eso antes, pero el error sigue siendo el mismo. ¿Alguna otra posible solución?

Comment: Es posible que los cambios no sean en efecto por que Heroku tiene tu settings.py anterior en la cache. Intenta a actulizar la cache. Funciona?

Comment: como se hace eso?? @WillRobertson